# DIV background image not displayed in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, html, background-image

I'm having a strange problem where my DIV background is not displayed in Firefox and Chrome, but appears perfectly fine in IE. Upon searching on Stackoverflow, I found several similar questions but none of the solutions worked for me unfortunately.

I read in a forum that it might have something to do with browser caching or that I'm using Windows XP. I believe browser caching isn't the problem in my case considering I'm testing my page offline, and the only online testing I've done was right after I uploaded the files. I haven't had the chance to check it on a different Windows platform (e.g. Vista), but even if this problem doesn't occur on Vista, naturally I would like my background image to appear across all platforms.

Please find below, my CSS and source code:

**CSS**

```
body {
margin: 0px;
background:url(../images/bground.jpg) fixed bottom;
}

.area {
width:738px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0 131px;
}

#menu {
width:738px;
height:41px;
position:absolute;
top:273px;
text-align: left;
}

#navlist li {
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

#sec-menu {
height:41px;
position:absolute;
right:131px;
top:50px;
text-align: right;
border-bottom:1px solid #bbb
}

#sec-navlist li {
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

#register {
position:absolute;
right:131px;
top: 110px;
}

#content {
width:1000px;
position:absolute;
top:273px;
text-align: center;
}
```

**Source Code**

```
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/register-over.png')">

<div class="area" style="height:343px; background:transparent url('images/header.png') top no-repeat center; position:relative">

<div id="sec-menu">
<ul id="sec-navlist">
    <li><a href="#" class="sec-menu">International Faculty</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sec-menu">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sec-menu">Sitemap</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>

<a href="#"><img src="images/register.png" alt="Register for KLVS 2011 Now!" width="91" height="89" id="register" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('register','','images/register-over.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" /></a>

<div id="menu">
    <ul id="navlist">
    <li class="menu-active">Home</li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu">About KLVS 2011</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu">Programmes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu">Accommodation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu">Exhibitors &amp; Sponsors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu">Call for Abstract</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

```
<div class="area" style="background:url(images/transparent-white_12.png) repeat-y"><br />
</div>
```

**The Problem**

My *'header.png'* image is not displayed in the first DIV that uses class *area*
Not sure if this is vital information, but I also apply the *area* class on another DIV calling a different background image, and that background image is displayed fine on all IE, Firefox and Chrome. I've tried removing `position:relative` and/or `transparent` from the first DIV but the problem still occurs.

I've also validated my file at http://validator.w3.org/ and I passed, so now I'm really stumped on what might have caused this. I really hope any kind soul on Stackoverflow could help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Could be a pathing issue. What happens if you change the url to "../images/header.png"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS has an error. Since you used shorthand, the `top` and `center` styles are confused. Put them together and it will be fine:

```
<div class="area" style="height:343px; background:transparent url('images/header.png') top center no-repeat ; position:relative">
```

`top center no-repeat`

Comment: Thanks, a few mins after I shared this Q on twitter, my friends pointed out the shorthand thing, too. A good reminder to myself in the future. Thanks again!